# Not able to forward ssh identity from jump box to target box

Tags: ssh, macos, ssh-agent

Let me make this a bit more clear. From my MacOS for work reasons I have to ssh to a jump box and then ssh to target boxes. Before I am able to ssh to jump box the ssh-agent will always ask for my passphrase for each new session. I added `UseKeychain yes` parameter under `Host *` in my `~/.ssh/config`. But after adding this, whenever I try to ssh to any target box from my jumpbox I get a `permission denied` error.

My question is:

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How can I fix this issue without removing `UseKeychain yes` from my ssh config?

Comment: Can you do ssh -vv youraccount@jumpbox, remove any sensitive info, and paste the result here - this should give us an idea on why it's failing to auth with the keychain

Comment: @Shōgun8 Shouldn't you avoid putting your ssh keys in jump hosts?

Comment: Also wanted to add the following, after adding `UseKeychain yes` if I do a ssh -J user@jump1.com user@host.com the login works fine. But if I break up the individual steps that's when I get the above error.

Comment: @  BoredToolBox, No. The entire purpose of asymmetrical (public/private key) encryption is so that literally anybody can have a copy of your *public key*. The public key, which is ***id_rsa.pub***, needs to exist on the jump box in order to verify your *private key* (which is the key that you should not share with anybody).

Comment: Don't put your *private key* (***id_rsa***)anywhere, keep that to yourself.

Comment: I got those two names reversed in my earlier comment so I deleted it. But the point is that you should place your public key on the jump server, and all servers that you need to login to.